# How to run an extended desktop to a vga and hdmi monitor

Tags: graphics-card, display, multiple-monitors, hdmi

My HP laptop has 1 hdmi port and 3 usb ports. Can I run an extended desktop to 2 monitors, 1 hdmi and one vga (with a usb to vga adapter because my pc doesn't have a vga port)? I've tried it but my pc doesn't detect the hdmi monitor. I don't need sound for either monitor. I use multiple monitors for karaoke and would like to use one vga and one hdmi monitor.

Comment: can you check if hdmi port is healthy?

Comment: yes, I have tested the hdmi port and it works.